# what are the main differences between mysql and postgres?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I want to create a new rails application and I'm not sure whether to use MySQL or Postgres. Which one is best and what is the difference between them?

UPDATE:

The project is a health-care project. It may contain more than 500 tables.

Comment: Use PostgreSQL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242812/pros-cons-of-mysql-vs-postgresql-for-production-ruby-on-rails-environment

Comment: You haven't mentioned any kind of specific requirements. If this is just a toy project, try  both and see which one you like more. This question is way to broad and opinion-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

postgres is secure, fast, and full of features but comparatively tricky to use.

MySql has its own benefits along with large user community and vast materials. Immensely helpful if you ever get stuck.

But ultimately it all comes to your preference and framework (apart from rails if your app requires any) support.

Read this for detailed comparison and insights: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Why_PostgreSQL_Instead_of_MySQL%3a_Comparing_Reliability_and_Speed_in_2007